# Pause the Stream until a value becomes true

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method returning Stream like this one:

```
Stream<int> getData() async* {
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    yield i;
  }
}
```

I want to read this `Stream` in batch. That means, read 10 data, pause for user input, then read next 10 data, again pause, read, pause... until the stream is finished.

How can I do this in dart?

Comment: see `StreamQueue` (or `StreamIterator`)

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: I got it! `StreamIterator` works well in this case. thanks

Comment: they say in the official docs that `StreamQueue` is better than `StreamIterator`

Comment: `StreamQueue` is indeed more useful. But I had trouble finding it. It is in `async` package for reference.